# "render ($user_profile)" in user-profile.tpl.php = no output

Tags: users

Following the discussion in http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile.tpl.php/7 I created a user-profile.tpl.php file in my theme directory, but the code

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($user_profile); print ("you are here"); ?>
</div>
```

prints the "you are here" but not the `$user_profile` array. Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing and enabling the devel module, then edit it so that it reads

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php krumo($user_profile); ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

That will show you what the data actually looks like...

Comment: Actually you could use the debug() function that's included with D7.

Answer (score 0):

or you may consider all variables that available for your template with debuggung like:

```
debug($variables);
```